# Azure B2C Custom Policy Can't Sign In

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am setting up a custom policy for Azure B2C and I have followed the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started

This allows me to create an account but if I try to authenticate with the new account I get:

`The username or password provided in the request are invalid.`

I have checked the settings detailed in this question:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/50355/unable-to-sign-on-using-custom-policy.html

Which involves verifying the **accessTokenAcceptedVersion** and **signInAudience**. These are set to null and AzureADMyOrg respectively.

I have made not other edits to the setup beyond those documented in the setup information.

I can authenticate with the user using the standard SignUpSignIn flow.

Any suggestions on other things I should check?

Comment: It might be helpful in this case to see your policies (Extensions and Policy). Do you have a public repo or can you share them (with private information redacted)?

Comment: The policies are the standard policies and extensions from the MS repo. Only the tenant name  and relevant application and proxy IDs have been updated as per the setup instructions.

Comment: I just followed that along and with the `LocalAccounts` starter, and it worked fine. That is, until I chose to `Reset Password` from the Azure Portal. Did you reset the user password by chance, thinking you might have had it wrong?

Comment: Base on your feedback I recreated the two Apps and it started to work. I must have made a mistake during their setup. Thanks for your help on this question and the other one :-)

Comment: My pleasure - The jump to the `Identity Experience Framework` does not come easily, but there's a great community backing it that got me through my challenges.

Answer (score 0):

In the [article](https://aka.ms/ief) we have added a section to automate the setup.
Delete your `IdentityExperienceFramework` and `ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework` application registrations. Then run the tool at https://aka.ms/iefsetup which will automate this article.

Comment: Do you know what the reason behind this issue was? i have the exact same issue raised. i have got a slight issue with this, 

Remove Facebook references - Removes the Facebook references from the deployment process when selected. Doing so, will provision the SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMFA starter pack with the User Journeys from the LocalAccount starter pack. - can I now set it up with Social and Local settings only (without MFA)

Comment: Deploy without FB references, then modify the Extension file and simply remove the MFA step from the user journey section. Re number the steps in the journey in sequential order.